# Geolocation.watchPosition() persistent error: POSITION_UNAVAILABLE on Windows v10.0.22621 (override is already in effect)

Tags: javascript, geolocation, location

watchPosition() works to initially retrieve location, but once location is changed, it throws error code 2 (POSITION_UNAVAILABLE) on every change. Though, it still returns the new position along with the error. I have tried both Chrome and Edge browser.

Steps to recreate:

1. Run live-editor code from
   [openjavascript.info](https://openjavascript.info/2022/12/11/map-live-user-location-using-leaflet-js/)
   and / or
   [tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/geolocation_watchposition.htm) (note: first link will auto watchPosition. second link you must press 'Watch Update' button)
2. Open Developer Tools > Ctrl+Shift+p > Show sensors > in 'sensors' tab, change location from drop down menu

The coordinates will update as expected, but an error will still be thrown everytime from the handler. Also, an error will appear in the Location section of the sensors tab stating "***override is already in effect***":
[image: browser view with error]

Comment: Ain't gonna do all that. Perhaps a [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39253172/navigator-geolocation-watchposition-return-position-unavailable)